# php-sip library - how to get the body of the SIP response

Tags: php, codeigniter, sip

I've just recently discovered the following lib: 
https://code.google.com/p/php-sip/

And I'm using it to send and rcv SIP messages.  So far so good. But in addition to just checking the value of the sip response, eg) 200 OK.  I need to get to the body of the response.

Has anyone found a way to do this? I'm currently reviewing the source code in PhpSIP.class.php but I don't see any public methods to getBody() or getResponse() etc.

Maybe I'll have to write one?  I'm not sure.  but i thought I'd check in case someone else knows how to do this. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to just modify the library and add my own method to expose the body of the SIP request.